# Ubuntu 17.10 ACPI ERRORS on USB BOOT: Core i5 6600 @ 4.2Ghz (non-k OC)

Tags: cpu, overclocking

I have a problem booting new live USB Ubuntu, looks like that:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- This should be related to a [bug](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=105491) with the Skylake chipset and requires you to update your BIOS to fix.
- You can also add [acpi_mask_gpe=0x6f](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=117481#c23) to the boot parameters as a work-around to have it continue.

Comment: I loose Overclocking capabilities with any newer bios, Windows works perfectly fine as is